# Alert if Label goes missing from a metric

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a metric 
DS_Info{desc="GOT",index="312",name="EC80",exported_namespace="s905"}

Is there anyway I can alert if any one of these labels go missing. Not the metric, just one of the labels.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to alert if any of the label is missing (empty): meaning if it is different from regex `.+`.

If you want to exclude the case where the metric itself is missing, you can use the `UNLESS` operator in the following way:

```
- alert: MissingLabelInInfoMetric
  rule: DS_Info UNLESS DS_Info{desc=~".+",index=~".+",name=~".+",exported_namespace=~".+"}
```

Which reads as "alert if DS_Info exists unless mentioned labels are not empty".